# Xcode won't download the exact HTML from website

Tags: html, ios, xcode, swift

I'm beginning to work with Swift and I got this error. I want to get the "8,660" (under "DOLAR VENTA") from this website: http://www.lanacion.com.ar/dolar-hoy-t1369 If you inspect the element of the number in the website, you'll find this:

```
<p id="dventa">8,<span>660</span></p>
```

And I thought I could get the data from that line.

The thing is that when I download it and print it to the output using this code:

```
@IBAction func obtenerPrecio(sender: AnyObject) {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.lanacion.com.ar/dolar-hoy-t1369")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

            //var urlContentArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<p id=\"dventa\">")

            println(urlContent)

        } else {

            println(error)

        }


    })

    task.resume()

}
```

What I get is this (I'll just show the part needed):

```
<p id="dventa">-</p>
```

Where's the "-" should be the data. What can I do to get the info? Thank you

Comment: It appears that the page you're requesting has some javascript that runs to update things. Since you have just loaded the raw HTML data statically instead of in a web view, you will not get this behaviour.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I need to equal a label's text to that info (8,660) can I do that in any way?

Comment: You will need to load the URL in a web view and then extract the data after it finishes loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, this data is being loaded by javascript.  A quick look of the website indicates the data is actually coming from [here](http://contenidos.lanacion.com.ar/json/dolar?callback=jsonpCallback), which is much simpler to parse.

```
dolarjsonpCallback({"Date":"2015-02-03T00:00:00","CasaCambioVentaValue":"8,66","BolsaCompraValue":"12,48","BolsaVentaValue":"12,48","InformalVentaValue":"13,3","CasaCambioCompraValue":"8,56","InformalCompraValue":"13,33"});
```

Comment: Sorry @Jeremy but, how did you get there? And, those aren't exactly the same numbers who appear in the website